# Styled-Components: Conditional styling with multiple props / states

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-props

I can't seem to find anything about this on Google...  Chances are it's there and I'm just not Googling the right thing.  I just keep finding what I've already done for one prop.

I currently have styles based on props and states.  And they work as expected.  But I've found myself in a scenario where I need a style where two props (true/false) are required at the same time for the desired result.

I was wondering if that was possible?

**The below works:**

```
${({ prop1 }) => !prop1 &&`
    // Some Styles when !prop1
`};

${({ prop2 }) => prop2 &&`
    // Some Styles when prop2
`};
```

**What I'm trying to do** is something like the below:

```
${({ prop1, prop2 }) => !prop1, prop2 &&`
    // Some Styles when !prop1 && prop2
`};
```

or

```
${({ prop1 && prop2 }) => !prop1 && prop2 &&`
    // Some Styles when !prop1 && prop2
`};
```

But that doesn't seem to want to work.  I don't think I'm far off... Maybe I am?  Any help would be great!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use the `css` method to do conditionals

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

${({ prop1, prop2 }) => !prop1 && prop2 && css`
    // Some Styles when !prop1 && prop2
`};
```

notice syntactially you are destructuring the props in your function.

`({prop1 && prop2})` == invalid syntax

Comment: That's great, thank you!  What does importing { css } do that styled doesn't though?  Bit confused by that

Comment: @Nick [**`styled-components` docs**](https://www.styled-components.com/#your-first-styled-component) recommend using `css` whenever writing an interpolation function to inject into the template string. `css` tells `styled-components` to accept the incoming string and apply to the styles. You should always use `css` when trying to do this, or you'll see unexpected behavior like you were experiencing :)

Comment: Thanks John!  Much appreciated :)